# Join query problems

Tags: php, sql, join

I have 2 tables.  My tables are as below.  I have as script called getTag.php.  The idea being a user wants to see all portfolio items I have tagged with say, php. However, I don't just want to do:

```
SELECT t.portfolio_item_id, p.*
FROM tags t
INNER JOIN portfolio p ON t.portfolio_item_id = p.id
WHERE t.$skillArea = '1'
```

I want to also get all the columns for the tag table too and join them on.  So if php =1 in the tag table, get the rest of the columns in the tag table and their values too along with corresponding portfolio item row in portfolio table

- **Portfolio**

  id
  item_name
  url
- **tags**

  portfolio_item_id
  php
  html
  design
  CSS

  etc...

Comment: i'm probably missing something, because it looks like you want `select * from...`

Comment: no you're not, I'm just not used to joins!  That was the problem, I thought I had to select tags again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*, p.*
FROM tags t
INNER JOIN portfolio p ON t.portfolio_item_id = p.id
WHERE t.$skillArea = '1'
```

You could just do `SELECT *` too but I have included t and p to demonstrate where you went wrong.

- t is the alias for the tags table
- p is the alias for the portfolio table
- t.* brings back all columns from the tags table
- p.* brings back all columns from the portfolio table

You had t.portfolio_item_id which would only bring back 1 column, where * is a `wildcard` which is used return all columns in that table.

Comment: thank you, I'm new to joins and sql so really appreciate the time you take to explain things

Comment: ahh so the first item in the select t.* corresponds to the FROM statement, which is why you don't need to specify the table?

Comment: @Nicola you have specified the table (t) which is an alias for tags.  It is the same as doing tags.*

Comment: no I know, I mean you can do just SELECT * instead of t.* because the from statement specifies the table